# OpenCV setting header search paths, library search paths and other linkers flags

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, opencv3.0

So after using

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4
```

I get

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.2.0_1/include/opencv4/opencv -I/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.2.0_1/include/opencv4 -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.2.0_1/lib -lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_quality -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

Header search path

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.2.0_1/include/opencv4
```

Library search paths

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.2.0_1/lib
```

Other linker flags

```
-lopencv_gapi -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn_objdetect -lopencv_dnn_superres -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_hfs -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_quality -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_sfm -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_superres -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_ml -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_video -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

But even after adding them to my header search paths, library search paths and other linker flags I still get this error

```
'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
```

Comment: May be a direction for research https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429936/opencv2-opencv-hpp-file-not-found-in-xcode and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953570/opencv2-opencv-hpp-file-not-found

Comment: Tried them but the error still exist

Comment: Try searching for it in Terminal `find /usr -name opencv.hpp`

Comment: Maybe it's `opencv2/core.hpp` now

Comment: Are you sure you installed OpenCV correctly? Please try ```pkg-config --modversion opencv``` and be sure it exist firstly.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `find: /usr/sbin/authserver: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.2.0_1/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp
find: /usr/local/mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64/keyring: Permission denied
find: /usr/local/mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64/data: Permission denied `

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk `(base) Yudhieshs-MacBook-Pro:C:C++ yudhiesh$ pkg-config --modversion opencv 
Package file '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc' appears to be empty
Package 'opencv' has no Name: field` What should I do here ?

Comment: Please show the actual full command you are using to compile/link - by editing your question - not in the comments area.

Comment: @yuRa Then your installation wrong. OpenCV doesnt exist.

Comment: When you installed OpenCV first check its existance

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk ok do you know any tutorials to install it then?

Comment: I can suggest [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-macos/)

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I completed it but still getting the same error